# Is it safe to expose the Firebase user auth uid to the public?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to know if it is safe to expose the Firebase auth uid to other users?

The Firebase user.uid is returned when a user authenticates with Firebase. This uid is often used in security rules and other Firebase modules like storage.

The reason to expose the Firebase user.uid to other users or the public are diverse. A chat tool where each message contains a field with the author user uid or a public user profile page with an url like this "user/:id".